# Is there a way to make doxygen process undocumented C code automatically?

Tags: c, doxygen

Usually it will ignore C files that are not documented, but I'd like to test the Callgraph feature for example, do you know a way around this without changing the C files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the variable `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` in your Doxyfile.

Comment: Also RECURSIVE was missing for me. Thanks