# C: Diagramming A Large Library

Tags: c, diagram, case, diagramming

Is there any tools to assist in diagramming a large C library? I am working on a project to port an existing C library to C++. The C library is largely undocumented with no diagrams. I would like to use a CASE tool to help me understand how the various files interact. There is extern variables in most of the files.

If possible I would prefer a visual diagram to better understand the flow of the code. I am not familiar with a diagramming tool for procedual lanagues (or if it even exists). I remember in college we use to use hierarchy and data flow diagrams for procedual languages.

I know there exists many tools for diagramming OO lanaguages, but I would like one for C. Any help would be appreciated.

**Suggestions**:

---

**[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)**

- [CodeProject Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/doxysetup.aspx)
- [Doxygen Official Tutorial](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html#extract_all)
- [Stackoverflow Force Undocumented C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645074/is-there-a-way-to-make-doxygen-process-undocumented-c-code-automatically)
- **[Remember to download Graphviz if you want a graphical representation and set the dot path ie:"C:\Program Files\Graphviz2.26.3\bin\"](http://www.graphviz.org/)**

> It can help you in three ways:
>
> It can generate an on-line
>   documentation browser (in HTML) and/or
>   an off-line reference manual (in )
>   from a set of documented source files.
>   There is also support for generating
>   output in RTF (MS-Word), PostScript,
>   hyperlinked PDF, compressed HTML, and
>   Unix man pages. The documentation is
>   extracted directly from the sources,
>   which makes it much easier to keep the
>   documentation consistent with the
>   source code. You can configure doxygen
>   to extract the code structure from
>   undocumented source files. This is
>   very useful to quickly find your way
>   in large source distributions. You can
>   also visualize the relations between
>   the various elements by means of
>   include dependency graphs, inheritance
>   diagrams, and collaboration diagrams,
>   which are all generated automatically.
>   You can even `abuse' doxygen for
>   creating normal documentation.

---

**[cppdepend](http://cppdepend.com/CppDependDownload.aspx)**

- opensource/academic and commercial licence (MSVS plugin)

> Improve your code base quality.
>   CppDepend is a tool that simplifies
>   managing a complex C\C++ (Native,Mixed
>   and COM) code base. Architects and
>   developers can analyze code structure,
>   specify design rules, do effective
>   code reviews and master evolution by
>   comparing different versions of the
>   code.  These Cases Studies shows the
>   utility of CppDepend to have a deep
>   view of your architecture, design and
>   implementation.   Refactor and Improve
>   your design and architecture.
>   CppDepend provides useful graphs to
>   analyze your design and architecture.
>   CQL language gives you a flexibility
>   to create your custom queries and have
>   a deep view of your code base.  here's
>   a sample of using CppDepend to assist
>   your refactoring.   Assist your
>   migration. Understanding the existing
>   migration. CppDepend helps you in your
>   migration process, you can find here
>   the advantages of using CppDepend in
>   your migration process.

---

**[ctag](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)**

- (nedit, vim, emacs) [VIM TUTORIAL](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/)

  - class names
  - macro definitions
  - enumeration names
  - enumerators
  - function definitions
  - function prototypes/declarations
  - class, interface, struct, and union data members
  - structure names
  - typedefs
  - union names
  - variables (definitions and external declarations)

---

**[csope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)**

- (cmd line, vim) [VIM TUTORIAL](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html)

  - Allows searching code for:
  - all references to a symbol
  - global definitions
  - functions called by a function
  - functions calling a function
  - text string
  - regular expression pattern
  - a file
  - files including a file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can generate various types of interaction diagrams - files, function calls, etc.  With the EXTRACT_ALL configuration variable set, it will generate diagrams and cross-referenced documentation even for code without documentation comments.

Answer (score 3):

[CppDepend](http://cppdepend.com/), if you work on Windows, extends Doxygen with a query language and ability to move in the dependency graph.

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen as mentioned by Nick Meyer is probably a good bet. You can also try the classic cross-referencing tools ctags and cscope, that you can use as standalone tools or integrated with your text editor.

Comment: cscope looks great but I am working in a Windows environment. It looks like a better version of MSVS NCB intelliense file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379615(VS.80).aspx). However, cscope gives you the ability to query your database.